# Is possible Ninject static property binding?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

Does ninject works for static property bindings?

I set `IEventHandlerFactory` with Ninject,

```
public class ServiceModule: NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
      Kernel.Bind<IEventHandlerFactory>().To<EventHandlerFactoryService>();
    }
}
```

And my static class

```
public static class DomainEvents
{
    public static IEventHandlerFactory EventHandlerFactory { get; set; }

    public static void Raise<T>(T domainEvent) 
    {
        EventHandlerFactory
            .GetDomainEventHandlersFor(event)
            .ForEach(h => h.Handle(event));
    }
}
```

But this does not bind to static property.

`DomainEvents.EventHandlerFactory` is Null

Is there any way to bind property?

Answer (score 3):

Since ninject doesn't have a concept of dividing "creating all bindings" and "using the kernel", there's of course no extension point for "tell me when the kernel is done with all bindings so i can do something".
With a static class it also doesn't make sense to request it from the kernel.

So the obvious answer is: no.

Of course, the obvious solution is just to extend your code where you're done building up the kernel (probably close to where you do `var kernel = new StandardKernel()`) with a call like

```
DomainEvents.EventHandlerFactory = kernel.Get<IEventHandlerFactory>();
```

### Alternative 1 - tying initialization to activation of another type

If that initialization should be tied to the activation of another type, let's say `IFoo`, you can also do:

```
kernel.Bind<IFoo>()
      .To<Foo>()
      .InSingletonScope()
      .OnActivation(x => 
          DomainEvents.EventHandlerFactory = kernel.Get<IEventHandlerFactory>());
```

### Alternative 2 - tying initialization to loading of a `NinjectModule`

You can sublcass `NinjectModule` and in it's `Load` you can initialize the static property. This works in case you can make sure the module is only loaded after the kernel is sufficiently initialized to create an `IEventHandlerFactory`.

### Disclaimer

Both alternatives probably suck because their not clear and not straight forward. They hide a dependency deep in some place. I'd only use one of these if the first approach is not feasible, for example because your writing a plugin and there's no extension point post-kernel initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need DomainEvents class to be static?

Maybe you can do as follows. Raise will still be static though.

You will have to call kernel.Get though.

```
public class DomainEvents
{
    public static IEventHandlerFactory EventHandlerFactory { get; set; }

    public DomainEvents(IEventHandlerFactory factory)
    {
         EventHandlerFactory = factory;
    }

    public static void Raise<T>(T domainEvent) 
    {
        EventHandlerFactory
            .GetDomainEventHandlersFor(event)
            .ForEach(h => h.Handle(event));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I use DomainEvents in domain entity operations. if I get it from constructor level, I will create objects in entity.

Comment: You will only need to do it once. Then you can use static method without creating object.